# When returning a Flux of type T from a controller it returns an incomplete list

Tags: reactive-programming, java-17, spring-boot-3, r2dbc-mysql

I have a get API that returns Flux<?>

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{category}/{code}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

@ResponseBody
public Flux findAllReferenceDataByCategory

But in the postman I get

```
[{

    "id": 1,

    "code": "MBNO",

    "description": "Mobile Number",

    "properties": {},

    "sequence": 1,

    "status": "ACTIVE"

}
```

As observed its an incomplete list, the expected result is a list of 6 objects. Please note this works for jdk11 and spring boot 2.7.3. It just fails for jdk17 and spring boot 3.1.4